# How to extract only month and day from DB to find out the birthday of a user and compare it with todays day to find out birthday

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I have a user table which contains user's dob now I would like to extract only month and day from that column so I can send birthday notification through jgrowl.

How can I do this? I am using MySql and using Date as type for date of birth...

is this allright?? ::

```
public function actionBirthday(){
        $user = Query::queryOne("SELECT MONTH(date_of_birth) AS birthmonth, DAY(date_of_birth) AS birthday FROM user");
//        $date =  date('m-d');
        if($user['birthmonth'] == date('m') && $user['birthday'] == date('d')) {
            if (Yii::$app->session['user_jSN4h1wSYC7D6JFOwh6M']['role'] != Yii::$app->params['user_role']['superadmin']) {
                $log = array(
                    'content' => "Today is " . ucfirst(Yii::$app->session['user_jSN4h1wSYC7D6JFOwh6M']->username) . "Birthday",
                    'type' => "user"
                );
                Notify::sendNotification($log);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: this:SELECT MONTH(date_of_birth) AS birthmonth, DAY(date_of_birth) AS birthday FROM user

Comment: try this  SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(field, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%m-%d');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select DATE(date_of_birth) as date, MONTH(date_of_birth) as month from table where column = value;

// date() will extract date and month() will extract month from date of birth column
```

Comment: This query will fail if user has their birthday on a leap year